# 'learning_logs' is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django, python-3.7, django-urls, traceback

I have been seeing the following error. How can I solve it?

Error: 'learning_logs' is not a registered namespace

## urls.py

````
"""Defines URL pattern for learning_logs"""
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
app_name = 'learning_log'
urlpatterns = [
    #Home page
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^topics/$', views.topics, name='topics'),
]```
  

#base.html

'''<p>
  <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}">Learning Log</a> -
  <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topics' %}">Topics</a>
</p>
{% block content %}{%endblock content %}
````

Comment: The `app_name` is `'learning_log'`, *not* `'learning_logs'` (so without the `s`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
###base.html
<p>
    <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Learning Log</a> -
    <a href="{% url 'topics' %}">Topics</a>
</p>
{% block content %}{%endblock content %}
```

This is because our book is out of date, I think.

A tip: try to use path functions instead of url functions in urls.py